# how to use scrapy with text list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

Hello all i worked on new project for convert ip to domain name with scrappy

i not find how to add list text ( ip.txt ) on my start url in scrappy , replace ( + IP ) with by text list

exepmle :

```
start_urls = [
    `"https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q= + ip"`]
```

-----------------------------------MY Code-----------------------------

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

lists = open(raw_input('IP list file name: '), 'r').read().split('\n')

class jeffbullasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "iptohost"
    allowed_domains = ["api.hackertarget.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=" + str(lists) ] 

    def parse(self, response):
       print response.xpath('//body//text()').get()
```

( i'm new on python , thanks you very mutch. )

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

lists = open(raw_input('IP list file name: '), 'r').read().split('\n')

class jeffbullasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "iptohost"
    allowed_domains = ["api.hackertarget.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=" + str(lists) ] 

    def parse(self, response):
       print response.xpath('//body//text()').get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

EDIT: also strip the ip before sending request

```
import scrapy

lists = open(raw_input('IP list file name: '), 'r').read().split('\n')

class jeffbullasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "iptohost"
    allowed_domains = ["api.hackertarget.com"]
    url = "https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q={}"

    def start_requests(self):
        for ip in lists:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url.format(ip.strip()), callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
       print(response.xpath('//body//text()').get())
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please approve the answer if it was what you were looking for :) you can check Scrapys tutorial https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

i have other problem i have added proxy rotation on scrapy and after i have saved with this command :

```
scrapy crawl iptohost -o some.json -t json &> some.text
```

my result not contain only my domain contain proxy result and my result domain

my result

```
    2019-11-10 10:39:50 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://197.157.219.25:8080> is DEAD
2019-11-10 10:39:50 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=61.112.2.178> with another proxy (failed 4 times, max retries: 5)
2019-11-10 10:39:50 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://139.59.99.119:8080> is DEAD
2019-11-10 10:39:50 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=195.11.184.130> with another proxy (failed 5 times, max retries: 5)
2019-11-10 10:39:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=195.11.184.130> (referer: None)
2019-11-10 10:39:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=185.179.235.40> (referer: None)
[u'capitalinstant.com']
[u'142.92.242.192']
[u'API count exceeded - Increase Quota with Membership']
[u'API count exceeded - Increase Quota with Membership']
[u'API count exceeded - Increase Quota with Membership']
```

how to remove proxy result for scrape only my domain result pleaz thanks you very mutch =)